# Rails: How to save associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So the scenario is I have 3 models. 2 of them are one-to-one and the 3rd is a reference data

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :post_content, autosave: true
  has_many :categories
end


class PostContent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end


class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :post
end
```

Where:

- Post is 1-to-1 with PostContent.
- Post can have many categories.
- Categories has a fixed data and is only being referenced to Post

What I'm trying to do is to persist it in the database with something like this:

```
def saveme
    content = PostContent.new
    content.content = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"

    category = Category.new
    category.type = "TRV"
    category.description = "Travel"
    category_list = Array.new([category])

    post = Post.new
    post.title = "title"
    post.banner = "bannerUrl"
    post.post_content = content
    post.categories = category_list

    post.save
end
```

I'm not sure how to use the create_associations. I'm getting an error on the current setup. Can you help me out?

```
can't write unknown attribute `post_id`
```

Thanks!

EDIT:
Here are my migrations for the associations:

```
class AddPostContentToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :posts, :post_content, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
class AddCategoryToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :posts, :category, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the post object before adding the associations (as a new object doesn't have an ID and that is what is used to make the association). Also, you need to save the association objects themselves first too. Finally you can use << to add to a has_many association.

See below:

```
def saveme
    content = PostContent.new
    content.content = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
    content.save # adding save here

    category = Category.new
    category.type = "TRV"
    category.description = "Travel"
    category.save # adding save here
    category_list = Array.new([category])

    post = Post.new
    post.title = "title"
    post.banner = "bannerUrl"
    #post.post_content = content - we are moving this
    #post.categories = category_list - we are moving this

    post.save

    post.post_content = content
    post.categories << category_list
end
```

You could also clean this up a lot too:

```
def saveme
    # create instead of new will save the record as part of the call
    content = PostContent.create(content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet") 
    categories = [Category.create(type: "TRV", description: "Travel")]

    post = Post.create(title: "title", banner: "bannerUrl")

    post.post_content = content
    post.categories << category_list
end
```

Comment: Didn't work, man. I'm getting an error in this line:
post.post_content = content

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column post_contents.post_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...ECT  "post_contents".* FROM "post_contents" WHERE "post_cont...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  "post_contents".* FROM "post_contents" WHERE "post_contents"."post_id" = $1 LIMIT 1):
  app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:26:in `saveme'

Comment: OK I know why, you need to save the association models first too. See updated answer.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column post_contents.post_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...ECT  "post_contents".* FROM "post_contents" WHERE "post_cont...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  "post_contents".* FROM "post_contents" WHERE "post_contents"."post_id" = $1 LIMIT 1):
  app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:48:in `saveme'.

Line 48 is: post.post_content = content

Comment: I'm getting a different error on your refactored code:
Invalid single-table inheritance type: TRV is not a subclass of Category.
in this line: post.categories << category_list

I've added my migrations in the question.

Comment: i've changed the "type" column into "cattype" as it's getting me errors. however, the refactored code gives me the same error:


PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column post_contents.post_id does not exist LINE 1: ...ECT "post_contents".* FROM "post_contents" WHERE "post_cont... ^ : SELECT "post_contents".* FROM "post_contents" WHERE "post_contents"."post_id" = $1 LIMIT 1


 app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:36:in `saveme'


Line 36 is: post.post_content = content

Comment: Yes type is a reserved word for Polymorphic models, you need a different name. What's the new error with my refactored code after you change the attribute to cattype?

Comment: Same thing (ERROR: column post_contents.post_id does not exist). See my reply before your post for the complete message.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply as I was overseas for a bit. It seems the other error I got is unrelated to this as it was because of my database being not built correctly. Accepting this answer.